# how to store Asp.net Register data in xml

Tags: asp.net

I design complete  registration page in Asp.net I want to store register data in xml file Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serialize an object containing registration info:

```
> [Serializable]
>     public class RegisterInfo
>     {

>         public string Username { get; set; }
>         public string Password { get; set; }
          ....

>     }
>     ...
>     RegisterInfo ri= new RegisterInfo()
>     {
>         Username = "dave",
>         Password = "somepassword"
>     };
      System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\reg_info.xml");
>     new XmlSerializer(typeof(RegisterInfo)).Serialize(file, ri);
```

Comment: I want to store multiple user data

Comment: Then serialize a List<RegisterInfo> or any other object that is suitable to the data you like to store.